# Generate a masonry layout and then apply gravity to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, physicsjs

Here's a weird one that I've been wracking my brain on.

I want to do two things, in order:

1. Generate a masonry-style layout from a list of divs, imgs, or whatever.  These will utilize images but they can be background images,  within the divs, or some other method that works.  This can be pure CSS or a jquery plugin.
2. Once the grid has been generated, apply a physics based plugin like '.throwable' to the individual divs/objects.  The objects will fall on each other, but overall retain their structure, much like you'd see in Angry Birds or something.

The goal here is to paste in a list of divs, let a jquery plugin or even pure CSS automatically figure out how to align them, and then apply gravity to the masonry grid.

The problem I've run into over and over is that the masonry grid is generated... but then when I apply a physics system to it, the individual objects snap back to a different position.  I think masonry wants them as "relative" while the physics system wants them in "absolute"? Not sure...

I have a rough version of my latest attempt up here if anyone wants to get an idea of what I'm attempting: http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/f5dm0zv8

Comment: I think the easiest thing you could try is using some kind of javascript plugin to generate the grid. Then for each image just use .offset() to get the position and create a physics body for it, placing the physics body using the position you get from offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jasper's reply hinted at the solution, although I'm not sure why things seemed to work this time for me.  I had tried multiple javascript/jquery based masonry plugins, and nothing had worked.  I ended up trying "http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html" and it ended up working for me.  I thought I had tried this one already - maybe not?  Anyways, I have a more or less working example here, but new issues have arisen: http://output.jsbin.com/runewidapi/2/